# Figure behavior varies when calling custom plot on single line or multiple lines

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

```matlab
function plot2(x)
    hold on
    fig = gcf();
    ax = gca();

    plot(ax, x)

    fig.Visible = true;
    figure('Visible', 'off')
    hold off
end
```

Why does

```
>> plot2([1 2]); plot2([2 1])
```

create two figures, but

```
>> plot2([1 2])
>> plot2([2 1])
```

one? We have

- `plot2()` <=> use 1 existing figure, create 1 new figure
- `>> plot2(); plot2()` <=> use figure X, create figure Y, use figure Y, create figure Z.
- `>> plot2()` `>>plot2()` <=> use figure X, create figure Y. use figure Y? create figure Z?

`disp(gcf)` before `hold off` show that new figs are being created in both cases, as in `Figure (25)`, `Figure (26)`.

Comment: I see you're using a pattern of starting your titles with the tag. [That's not how titles are supposed to look](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349612/5211833). Tags go in tags, not in the title. That's what the whole tagging system is designed for after all. Also note that you can add more than a single (language) tag, e.g. [tag:matlab-figure] would be relevant here.

Comment: @Adriaan I disagree, but don't always mind my titles edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that calling `plot2([1 2]); drawnow(); plot2([2 1])` on a single line uses one figure the same as two separate `plot2` calls. So at a high level it's likely due to the graphics buffer not being flushed when calling both on a single line without `drawnow`.

However, debugging we can see this is caused by the slightly odd order of operations called by your `plot2` function, which has ambiguous handling of figures by relying on `gcf` and using calls to `hold` out-of-order and without specifying the `hold` target axes.

In the below lines, where I've written a code line it as an extract from `plot2` during a given command call:

```
>> plot2([1 2]); plot2([2 1])

% Calling through "plot2([1 2])"
hold on      % creates a figure and axes if one doesn't exist, or hold current
fig = gcf(); % gets the figure referenced by "hold"
ax = gca;    % gets the axes referenced by "hold"
plot(ax,x)   % plots on these axes

fig.Visible = true; % make the current figure visible
figure('Visible','off') % Create NEW figure, hidden. At this point you have 2 figures
hold off     % does NOTHING, sets hold to "off" for new (invisible) 
             %  figure which is the default anyway


% Calling through "plot2([2 1])"
hold on      % holds "on" the CURRENT figure. This will depend whether the graphics buffer 
             %  has been flushed. If not then the current figure is the hidden one created 
             %  in the previous call, if it has then the current figure is the most recent 
             %  visible figure. This is *not* specifically noted in the docs.
fig = gcf(); % gets the same figure referenced by "hold"
ax = gca;    % gets the same axes referenced by "hold"
plot(ax,x)   % plots on these axes

fig.Visible = true; % make the same "current" figure as above visible. When running with a 
                    %  graphics flush in between, this figure will already be visible 
                    %  due to the above behaviour
figure('Visible','off') % Create ANOTHER NEW figure, hidden. 
                        %  At this point you will have 3 figures!
hold off     % does NOTHING, sets hold to "off" for new (invisible) 
             %  figure which is the default anyway
```

You can verify my last comment about ending up with 3 figures using `allFig = findall(0,'type','figure');` which will show all current figure objects including those which are hidden.